# htaccess modrewrite regex duplication

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1
```

and I'm trying to redirect all:
/blog/blog/xxxxxxx to /blog/xxxx

For some reason it doesn't seem to work... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVM... solved by doing the following:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```